# List local git repos in subfolders

Tags: linux, git, repository

On my webservers, I like to create git repos in various configuration folders like `/etc/apache2` and so forth, so I can keep track of changes I've made to the config files over time. As I install more services like proftpd, fail2ban, postfix, etc, I add more git repos to each folder.

At this point, I can't remember where they all are located. Short of typing

```
find . -type d -iname ".git"
```

is there any way to search for all the git repos in a certain directory, and **bonus points**, show the branch and its clean/dirty status? Something like:

```
./etc/apache2/.git  [master*]
./etc/proftpd/.git  [master*]
./etc/fail2ban/.git  [master]
./etc/postfix/.git  [master]
```

where the asterisk is showing that the repo has uncommitted changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create separate repos for each product.

In your home directory, create one directory to hold everything and make a single git repo.  For example, say your hostname is `myserver`, create

```
~/myserver
```

and make THAT the git repo, with everything else under it, for example

```
~/myserver/.git
~/myserver/etc
~/myserver/etc/network
~/myserver/var
~/myserver/opt
...
```

If you want to manage multiple hosts, set up a `~/config` directory and create hostname folders under that.  You should need only one git repo.

Comment: That would work if it was set up all out of one directory. All of these services are at the root of the linux filesystem, i.e., /etc, /var, etc. I'm not going to make a git repo for the whole filesystem.

Comment: Don't. Make a git repo _in your home directory_ that mirrors only the directories in which you need to keep copies of files.  Do the work in your home-directory copy and then deploy the modified files to their "real" location.  It's a little more work but much cleaner as you don't pollute system directories with spurious .git subdirectories.